# Sumar columna con input de una tabla HTML

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5

estoy desarrollando un sistema en el cual tengo una tabla que posee columnas con diversos calculos. Para la ultima columna con class "sumando_costo" necesito calcular su total. Pero no he logrado acceder al valor de la columna, ya que no se como acceder a un input en un td de una tabla. Me gustaría saber como debo llegar a el.

```
   <div class="table-responsive">
                 <table id="tabladetalle" class="table table-bordered table-sm datatable-row-responsive mb-3" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                           <tr class="bg-teal-400">

                                <th>stock</th>
                                <th>Cant. solicitada a bodega(Kg/Lt)</th>
                                <th>Pedido adicional</th>
                                <th>Devolución a bodega</th>
                                <th>Real utilizado(Kg/Lt)</th>
                                <th>Costo real</th>
                              </tr>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                                     <?php
                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                echo "<tr>";

                echo "<td><h6>".$row['stock']."</h6></td>";
                echo "<td><h6><input type='text' class='form-control'  value='0'></h6></td>";
                echo "<td><h6><input type='text' class='form-control' ' value='0'></h6></td>";
                echo "<td><h6><input type='text' class='form-control'  value='0'></h6></td>";
                echo "<td><h6><input type='text' class='form-control'  value='0'></h6></td>";

                echo "<td><h6><input type='text' class='form-control sumando_costo'  value='0'></h6></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                 }
                 ?>  
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
```

Estoy intentando acceder al valor del campo sumando_costo de la siguiente manera, pero me arroja un error de propiedad textContent:

```
 var filas=document.querySelectorAll("#tabladetalle tbody tr");

    filas.forEach(function(e) {

    var columnas=e.querySelectorAll("td");

    var costoreal = parseFloat(columnas[10].textContent);

     console.log("costoreal"+ costoreal);
```

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que tratas es obtener el valor del input en la columna 10, puedes utilizar `find()` de jQuery asi:

```
var filas=document.querySelectorAll("#tabladetalle tbody tr");

filas.forEach(function(e) {

var columnas=e.querySelectorAll("td");

var costoreal = parseFloat($(columnas[10]).find('input').val());

 console.log("costoreal"+ costoreal);
```

Comment: funciono perfecto, gracias !

Answer (score 0):

Sería bastante mas fácil si le agregas clases a cada fila entonces puedes seleccionar una fila entera y asignarle los totales, algo así:

```js
const totalFila1 = [...document.querySelectorAll(".fila1:not(.sumando_costo)")].reduce((p, c) => p + parseInt(c.value), 0);
const totalFila2 = [...document.querySelectorAll(".fila2:not(.sumando_costo)")].reduce((p, c) => p + parseInt(c.value), 0);

document.querySelector(".fila1.sumando_costo").value = totalFila1;
document.querySelector(".fila2.sumando_costo").value = totalFila2;
```

```css
td input {
  width: 50px
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
      Sub totales
    </td>
    <tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h6><input type='text' class='form-control fila1' value='1' /></h6>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h6><input type='text' class='form-control fila1' value='1' /></h6>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h6><input type='text' class='form-control fila1' value='1' /></h6>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h6><input type='text' class='form-control fila1' value='1' /></h6>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h6><input type='text' class='form-control  fila1 sumando_costo' value='0'></h6>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h6><input type='text' class='form-control fila2' value='10' /></h6>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h6><input type='text' class='form-control fila2' value='10' /></h6>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h6><input type='text' class='form-control fila2' value='10' /></h6>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h6><input type='text' class='form-control fila2' value='10' /></h6>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h6><input type='text' class='form-control  fila2 sumando_costo' value='0'></h6>
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

obviamente se puede hacer lo mismo dinámicamente sin clases, agregando otras o bien agregándole clases a los `tr`.